# Checks In PHP are not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working in PHP. i have made a form named as Donor.php and a connect it to database. Now I am trying to apply checks in on it in PHP. But their is a problem. As I have applied checks for empty fields in PHP on a form but these checks are not working. Please check out my code. As my work is stuck just because of this problem. My code file is here:

Donor.php

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $first_name=$_POST['firstname'];
 $last_name=$_POST['lastname'];
 $Country=$_POST['country'];
 $City=$_POST['city'];
 $Gender=$_POST['gender'];
 $Email=$_POST['email'];
 $Password=$_POST['pwd'];

include_once "connectionn.php";
$emailChecker=mysql_real_escape_string($Email);
$sql_email_check=mysql_query("Select Email FROM user WHERE Email='$emailChecker'");
$email_check=mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check);


if((empty($first_name)) ||(empty($last_name)) ||(empty($City)) ||(empty($Gender)) ||(empty($Email)) ||(empty($Password))) {
    $errorMsg='We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.'; 

    if (empty($first_name)) {
   $errorMsg.='$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
   header('Location: Donor.php');
}
    if(empty($last_name)){
        $errorMsg.='lastname';
        header('Location: Donor.php');
        }
        if(empty($City)){
        $errorMsg.='City';
        header('Location: Donor.php');
        }
        if(empty($Gender)){
        $errorMsg.='Gender';
        header('Location: Donor.php');
        }
        if(empty($Email)){
        $errorMsg.='email';
        header('Location: Donor.php');
        }
        if(empty($Password)){
        $errorMsg.='Password';
        echo "$errorMsg.";
        header('Location: Donor.php');
        }
    }else if($email_check>0){
        $errorMsg="invalid";
        }else{
            $sql="INSERT INTO user (User_ID,First_Name, Last_Name, gender, city, Email, Password) VALUES (NULL,'$first_name', '$last_name','$Gender','$City','$Email','$Password')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$UserID="SELECT max(User_ID) as usr from user";
$userIDResult=mysql_query($UserID);
if($userIDResult === false)
{
    die(mysql_error());
    }
while($R=mysql_fetch_array($userIDResult)){
    $usrID= $R['usr'];

    }
    $donor="INSERT INTO donor(User_ID, Country)Values('".$usrID."','$Country')";
    $resultdonor=mysql_query($donor);




mysql_close();
header('Location: DonorPro.php');

            }
}

    ?>
<?php 
include "Header.php";
//include "registration.php";
 ?>
<div class="DonorDiv">
<h1>Lets Join:</h1>
<form name="input" action="" method="post" <?php print"$errorMsg"; ?>>

First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"  id="r">
<?php print "$first_name"; 
// if (!isset($_POST['firstname'])) { 
    //echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
//}
    ?>


Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"  id="u" <?php print "$last_name";?>> <br>
Institution: <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Institution"  id="" <?php print "$Institution";?>>
City: <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City"  id="" <?php print "$City";?>><br>
Country: <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" id="" <?php print "$Country";?>><br>
Gender: <input type="text" name="gender" placeholder="Gender"  id="" <?php print "$Gender";?>><br>
Email Address: <input type="Email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="g" <?php print "$Email";?>><br>
Password:<input type="Password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" id="v" <?php print"$Password";?>><br>

<input type="submit" src="images/button(9).png" alt="Submit" id="q">
</form>
</div>

<?php include "Footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Narrow down your problem show us where you stuck?

Comment: Try not nesting the if statements.

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit if i pressed submit button without filling any feild, its not showing any error massage. but its also not move towards else condition as their is INSERT query. But the values are not going to database as well. what to do??

Comment: `include_once "connectionn.php";` maybe its `include_once "connection.php";`

Comment: @Sharky no, Its connectionn.php...

Comment: huh!!! your code is **WIDE** open for sql injection! And you're using a query to get the id you will insert?! just use auto_increment on your primary key in your table, more efficient, and surely won't cause issues, your code now may cause issues. Finally as Dholakiya said narrow down your problem, so we can understand what's going on... Tell us what you're seeing, what exactly do you mean by `are not working`?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP mysql lib is deprecated, you should consider using myslqi or php PDO instead.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

You should also be careful : `$first_name` and the other variables as they are not defined when you display the form, so you will get warnings.

Anyway, your problem is that this check is always false :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

The easiest (but not the best) way to correct that is to add a hidden input in your form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden">
```

Comment: Or just give submit a name and value so it will be true.

Answer (score 1):

You have to quit the PHP script after telling the browser to redirect to another page:

```
header('Location: Donor.php');
exit;
```

(Besides SQL injection and some other problems.)